# How to provide relative paths in CSS file in MVC3

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller

I am working on changing themes dynamically in css files.
I have multiple css files and the images used in the css files are stored in 
Content/themes/base/images/image.jpg
But i am not able to see the images
I searced other blogs and some one told me that they are relative the css files and images so i tried to change the default Css file that is Site.css
But i am also not able to view the image

Here is what i tried:

```
background-image:url('../../images/image.jpg');
```

Please help me...

Comment: you can use it like this: background-image:url('/Content/themes/base/images/image.jpg'); - not relative

Comment: Please check this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2188218/relative-paths-in-javascript-in-an-external-file

Comment: @kleinohad hey thanx i tried this worked i had nt placed my css file properly..it is working now

Comment: possible duplicate of [in asp.net.mvc, what is the correct way to reference images inside of css](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5730528/in-asp-net-mvc-what-is-the-correct-way-to-reference-images-inside-of-css)

Answer (score -1):

you can use it like this: background-image:
`url('/Content/themes/base/images/image.jpg');` - not relative

Comment: This is not useful if the application is deployed under a virtual directory.