# Background image not working after published

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Im stil develop the MVC project i have background image, iam publish project in my local saver, but not see in my saver my image, but image realy work my pc , what is the problem ? please give me a solution?

Image Path

```
 <body  style=" background-image:url(../../img/home_bg.jpg);>
```

Comment: Where is the `img` directory located relative to the root of your website? What is the request path of the page you're visiting? How did you come to decide to use `../../` in your image path?

Comment: its get the auto , path make a auto

Comment: Have a look at this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/851724/css-background-image-what-is-the-correct-usage and this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5730528/in-asp-net-mvc-what-is-the-correct-way-to-reference-images-inside-of-css

Comment: Sir, thanks Im try to this .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Relative Path using "/"

```
/RootDirectory/img/home_bg.jpg
```

If image folder is within the RootDirectory Then Use Below

```
/img/home_bg.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution,

finaly its working

```
 url('/img/home_bg.jpg');
```